# Not able to bind values from Thymeleaf based UI form to a controller in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My application is not able to bind a form value from an `Thymeleaf + HTML` based UI to a `Spring Boot` controller.

I am getting that value as `null` when I do a System.out.println into the controller.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Get your greeting <a href="/greeting">here</a></p>
        <form action="/publishMessage" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>CHARGE</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <textarea th:field="*{messageBody}" name="" cols="90" rows="40">
                        {
                        "firstname": "Jose",
                        "lastname": "Long"
                        }
                        </textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Publish CHARGE message"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PublishMessageController.java**

```
@Controller
public class PublishMessageController {    
    @PostMapping("/publishMessage")
    public String publishMessage(Message message, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        System.out.println("into the publishMessage method..........");
        String messageBody = message.getMessageBody();
        System.out.println("messageBody: " + messageBody);
        return "result";
    }
}
```

**Message.java**

```
import lombok.*;

@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Message {
    private String messageBody;
}
```

**Output:**

```
into the publishMessage method..........
messageBody: null
```

Comment: Sorry but the `message` is not put into `model` in your controller at all. A unit test would be also nice.

Comment: Yes, it is not but my question is more of from the UI binding side. The `message` object is not getting bound once we receive data from the UI to controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message never gets put into the model, so you can't use it as variable in your controller.

[Spring model attributes](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html)

[Handling the command object](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form)

BTW: The method shouldn't return "result" but the String of the message body.

Put your messageBody to model where you show your form:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showForm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Model model) {
  ... 
  String messageBody = ...
  model.addAttribute("messageBody", messageBody);
  ...
}
```

To use this in your view, add `th:action` and `th:object` to your form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/publishMessage}" th:object="${messageBody}" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Now you're able to use it in your controller method via annotation in the parameters:

```
@PostMapping("/publishMessage")
public String publishMessage(@ModelAttribute(value="messageBody") String messageBody, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
     ...
     return messageBody;
}
```

You could do this with the whole message instead of the body, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above input from SHEIX made some changes and it worked.

**ShowFormController.java**

```
@Controller
public class ShowFormController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", new Message());
        return "show";
    }

}
```

**show.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h3>
    <a href="/showForm">Go Back</a>
</h3>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/publishMessage}" th:object="${message}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>CHARGE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea th:field="*{messageBody}" name="" cols="90" rows="40" style="background-color: beige">

                </textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Publish CHARGE message"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Message.java**

import lombok.*;

```
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Message {
    private String messageBody = "{\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t\t\"name\": \"John\"\n" +
            "                    }";
}
```

**PublishMessageController.java**

```
@PostMapping("/publishMessage")
public String publishMessage(@ModelAttribute(value = "messageBody") String messageBody, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    System.out.println("into the publishMessage method..........");
    System.out.println("messageBody: " + messageBody);
    return "result";
```

**result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h3>
    Thanks !!!
    <a href="/">Go Back</a>
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```